# Kurento: Link library in OpenCV module

Tags: opencv, curl, cmake, libcurl, kurento

I'm writing an OpenCV module to go with Kurento Media Server.
I'm reading a file from an URL using lib curl.

The code I have is as follows:

```
#include<curl/curl.h>

size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    vector<uchar> *stream = (vector<uchar>*)userdata;
    size_t count = size * nmemb;
    stream->insert(stream->end(), ptr, ptr + count);
    return count;
}

Mat curlImg(const char *img_url, int timeout=10)
{
    vector<uchar> stream;
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, img_url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &stream);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return imdecode(stream, -1);
}

Mat image = curlImg(link);
```

Upon building it: I get the following warnings and the resultant package is not installed:

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol curl_easy_cleanup found in none of the libraries 
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol curl_easy_perform found in none of the libraries
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol curl_easy_setopt found in none of the libraries
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol curl_easy_init found in none of the libraries

My guess is that there is a problem with linking the libraries in CMakeLists.txt

So how should I link these libraries?
Is target_link_libraries() the correct way? If so, what is the syntax?

**Edit:**

These are the ways I've tried so far.

**1**

```
SET(requiredlibs)

FIND_PACKAGE(CURL)
IF(CURL_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    SET(requiredlibs ${requiredlibs} ${CURL_LIBRARIES} )
ELSE(CURL_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find the CURL library and development files.")
ENDIF(CURL_FOUND)
```

**2**

```
target_link_libraries (curl)
```

**3**

```
SET(${CURL_LIBRARIES} )
```

Comment: You can find an example of target_link_librearies [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server/blob/15f6a5f12e336292abe78b28afe57946d860be84/server/CMakeLists.txt#L29).

Comment: How are you linking them now?

Comment: I've tried :

target_link_libraries (curl) and 

SET(${CURL_LIBRARIES} )

Both did not work.

Comment: Try to edit your question with what you tried and with your `CMakeList.txt` file (at least the relevant parts)

Comment: @santoscadenas, I don't know how to link them hence I didn't add it in the question. Normally I give the executable name which won't work here I suppose.

Comment: Just copy the relevant parts of the cmake file, to know how are you creating the module.

Comment: I have kept it as it was generated for now since I don't know the proper syntax with the exception of a single line. But I'll add in that part.

Comment: In option 1 how are you defining CURL_* variables?

Comment: @santoscadenas, I'm not. I found this code as a suggestion to another question and tried it out. I have no idea how I'm supposed to link it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the main folder project `CMakeLists.txt` where other requires are done, you need to add:

```
pkg_check_modules(CURL REQUIRED curl)
```

Then in folder `src/server` you need to modify CMakeLists.txt file as follows:

```
generate_code (
   MODELS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/interface
   SERVER_STUB_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/implementation/objects
   SERVER_IMPL_LIB_EXTRA_LIBRARIES ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried [santoscadenas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36494105), but it did not work.

I had to change `curl` to `libcurl` in `CMakeLists.txt` of the main folder project:

```
pkg_check_modules(CURL REQUIRED libcurl)
```